# JavaFX8 TreeTableView multiple root items

Tags: javafx-8, treetableview

```
TreeItem<FileModel> root = new TreeItem<FileModel>(playlist);
treeTblViewFiles.setRoot(root);
treeTblViewFiles.setShowRoot(true);
```

The code above sets one root item, but I need to have several so called root items with expandable list of child items. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You make a parent root, which you don't show.

That parent's children may also be roots, which you show.

Comment: Additional info: The root can be hidden by setting `showRoot="false"` on the TreeTableView.